# Struts2 action from Servlet

Tags: servlets, struts2

I am using Servlet in Struts2. Once the process in Servlet is completed, I need to call a Struts2 action. I am using `<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/myServlet"/>` in my struts.xml. How can I call a Strtus2 action from my Servlet?

Comment: for what you are using Servlet in your struts2 application?

Comment: Resolved : Added <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
     <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>  in web.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved : Added `<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>` in web.xml

Comment: Place Correct mark on this answer if it has solved your problem